# Nested foreach put into a string array in C#

Tags: c#, nested-loops

So I have an array coming in with hotels information and one piece I need out of it is the location of each hotel so then I can send that into a different method. So I have my first foreach setup, but now I am wondering how to collect all of the data on the locations into a string array so I can send that out after all of the hotels are read. Can someone help, thanks.

```
    // API call to get the info
    ContentAPI.BasicHotelMedia[] rawData = DataHelper.NewContentAPI().GetBasicHotelMedia(ProductCode, ProductYear, SiteBrand);
    //setting up the datatable
    DataTable dtHotels = InitHotelTable();
    //set my variables
    foreach (ContentAPI.BasicHotelMedia item in rawData)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtHotels.NewRow();
        dr["HotelCode"] = item.BasicHotelCode;
        dr["HotelDescription"] = item.BasicDescription;
        dr["WiFi"] = item.HasWifi;

        // This is the variable that i need set in the string array so i can send into another method
        dr["SellingLocation"] = item.BasicSellingLocation;

        // Add other raw data
        // Get other info about the hotel
        GetHotelMedia(item.BasicHotelCode, ProductYear, item.HasWifi, ref dr);

        dtHotels.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try declaring a string array and adding to it on the line in question, seems pretty simple?

Comment: So you are saying just set it to a string array instead of the dr["SellingLocation"]?

Comment: why do you need it as a string[]? isn't it one record?

Comment: the method that i want to call is this one private DataTable GetIncludedHotels(string[] locations) which then runs through the locations and gives me the different ones out in tabs

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using a List instead of initializing a string[]. They're just easier to work with.
Llike this:

```
var locations = new List<string>();

    foreach (ContentAPI.BasicHotelMedia item in rawData)
    {
        ...

        locations.Add(item.BasicSellingLocation);

    }

OtherMethod(locations.ToArray());
```